# How do I change the folder where Dropbox saves my screenshots?

Tags: macos, dropbox

By default, Dropbox saves screenshots in `~/Dropbox/Screenshots`.

How do I change the folder where these screenshots are saved?

I'm running macOS:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.4
BuildVersion:   16E195
```

Comment: If it's not in the configuration option menu, it means, you can't without changing the DropBox folder itself

Comment: Disable screenshots in Dropbox preferences and set the folder in the OS (I assume Mac).

Comment: Are you on a Windows PC or a Mac?